# Facebook graph api photos on my website legally

Tags: facebook, image, api, facebook-graph-api, image-processing

So I am making a website and I really want to use a lot of the beautiful images on facebook pages on my site. A lot of them are on facebook and I'm not sure the best and most legal way to do this is. There are a ton of articles online about this but they are wishy washy and have left me still confused on what I can can't do.

So what I think I've concluded is I can't download images, save them on my database, and change them in any way without consent of the facebook page. This is true even if they are public I think. Although I can use the graph api on anything that is public.

I'm just very confused with the whole image copyright world right now and would love some insight.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about image copyright not programming.

Comment: I guess you could say that, but in the grand scheme of things these kind of decisions are what make or break coders. I think it is fair to discuss what are the best practices involving image content.

Answer (score 0):

You can you **Facebook Graph API** to retrieve all of your photos.
If you're developing your own site, you can create an Facebook App, this app has permission of getting photos.
Then, you grant this app to authorize with your facebook account. Once you grant the app, you have an **access token** to retrieve photos via Facebook Graph API.

Comment: I think I worded my question poorly then. I am trying to get photos from facebook pages, which are public and require no access token. So I am more curious what is right and wrong in this case. Can I take that accessable url and use carrierwave or is that 'going to far.'